# How to do percentage height and width in Android?

Tags: android, layout, dimension

I'm trying to set a button to 60% height and 60% width of the physical device.

Since the size of the screen is user-dependent, using dips is out of the question.

How can we do percentage height and width in Android? E.g.:

```
 <Button android:layout_width="60%" android:layout_height="60%"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `layout_weight` attribute. If you've got the parent layout set to 10 weight, then you can set a weight of 6 in your `Button`.

There's quite a bit on the topic on Stack Overflow:

[Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

... or on the official Android blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible with [Guidelines](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7#4511) positioned with percentage values

[image: Layout Editor]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```