# Even distribution of views in a layout

Tags: android-layout

Is there any way, I can add UI components (Buttons in my case) to any layout (RelativLayout in my case) and width of parent gets evenly distributed among all views.

say parent width = 100;

if I add 10 Buttons - all buttons should be of width 10.

thanks.
m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `LinearLayout` you can make use of `layout_weight` to evenly distribute the size. 

 For eg, if you have two buttons, to take half width each of its parent, you can give `"layout_weight=1"` in both the buttons. So both of them would share the space.
Checkout the layout_weight documentation for more details

Comment: thanks, it works. Also found another link discussing problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android