# Android setLayoutParams not working on API16

Tags: android, xml, android-button, android-tablelayout

I'm adding buttons to a TableLayout (TableRow) and I want to have 10 buttons tops per row but when using API16(maybe all API10 > but i didn't test for that) it just cuts out after 5 buttons (too large I assumed, that's why I tried wrap_content on them, also tried to pad to 1,1,1,1 and it worked on the API 10 making them very small but nothing happend on API16) this occurs on the emulator and my device too.

This is the result I want: http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2243/fe32.png (API10)

This is the result I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTlHZ.png (API16)

java:

```
   public class Keyboard extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        TableLayout TblLayout;
        TableRow tr;
        String[] numRow = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
        String[] engKeys = {"q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard);

            TblLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);
            createRows(numRow);
            createRows(engKeys);
        }

        public void createRows(String[] keyValues){
               int i = 0;
                while (i < keyValues.length) {
                    if (i % keyValues.length == 0 || i % 10 == 0) {
                        tr = new TableRow(this);
                        TblLayout.addView(tr);
                        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams( 
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                    Button btn = new Button(this);
                    btn.setText(keyValues[i]);
                    btn.setGravity(1);
                    btn.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    btn.setId(i);
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
                    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                    tr.addView(btn);
                    i++;
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tblLayout"
     >

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `LinearLayout` with `weightSum` attribute

[How to set Table width and number of Columns in TableLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719380/how-to-set-table-width-and-number-of-columns-in-tablelayout-in-android)

If you set `android:weightSum="1"` and use `android:layout_weight="0.1"` for each `Button` it will work in all devices, however it's very possible that text can get cropped. To avoid cropping, you need to dynamically calculate available width and determine how many rows you can insert that every `Button` text is fully visible.

Comment: I'll do this if I have to but why is my code working on lower API but not on the higher ones? i couldn't find anywhere that stated that any of the above functions got deleted or deprecated with the newwer API's

Comment: Are you using the same device or different?

Comment: I've tested this on ADT's emulators (Nexus one 4.1.2 API16 and 2.3.3 API10) also tested on my real devices SGS2 4.1.2 and Galaxy mini 2.3.3 and the results are the same (works on all 2.3.3 devices but not on the 4.1.2 devices)

Comment: It's not even setLayoutParams only, basic stuff like .setHeight and .setWidth affect the lower API but not the new ones, what's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the problem, had to add the button into the TableRow before changing it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to this question but explanation why `setLayoutParams` behaves differently depending on api version.
if you compare `setLayoutParams` implementation in api 17 and 16 you will notice one difference which is `resolveLayoutParams()`; that used in api 17 as opposed to older versions. that method does the trick up setting most recent layout params. So if you want your `setLayoutParams` work same way in all apis make sure you call it after `onMeasure()`