# How to fill layout with content with different weights like a percentage widths?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have horizontal layout with total weight 10.
I want to put some content with different width on it.
I want my content on it looks like next proportion of it's widths:
3:5:1:1
i.e. like a table with columns 30%, 50%, 10%, 10%
How to organize this?
Now I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:useLargestChild="true"
    android:weightSum="10" >
```

And TextViews with different weights like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

But it didn't work. Views are located out of screen.
If I change match_parent to wrap_content it looks OK while I don't place large text on it, then TextView grows up.
I don't want it, I want to show only that part of text, that will be wrap in current 30, or 50, or etc %.

Comment: See similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in limit text in container using

```
android:maxEms="<Wieght of this TextView>"
```

Seems to work ok. But I'm not sure is it correct or not.