# Planning an Android UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I am just starting out with Android and I am struggling to familiarize myself with the the views available.

I am working on an app for a tablet where I would ideally have a "split screen", with the left-hand side essentially being a vertical list of items. On selecting an item from the left-hand pane the right hand pane would show details of the thing selected. ( I guess this would be like the email app UI ).

I could build this interface in C# or a web based system - where would you begin on an Android system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) is exactly what you need.

The great thing about it that if you switch to portrait mode you'll have each "pane" on a separate Activity (or screen).

If you need to implement it for pre 3.0 check you the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) (v4).

Answer (score 0):

A vertical list of items would be a `ListView` for which you could set an `onListItemSelected` listener. That listener would modify the contents of whatever you decide to put into the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with a horizontal linear layout.

From there, implement vertical linear layouts, listLayouts, etc... on each the left and right sides.  For these secondary tiered layouts, give them widths in 50% weights so that each side takes up half of your screen!

A link that speaks about setting linear layouts in terms of weights and how to do it!

[Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), but as far as familiarizing yourself with views available, take a look at the Android Design Site, specifically the [Building Blocks](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/index.html) section. It shows you a bunch of different UI patterns to use which you can build from included views.