# how to set width of button with respect to the resolution available on android device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

my current android project requires the width of button should be set dynamically depending on the resolution available on device

i want to arrange 9 button in a row but the size will depend on the resolution available

for the current scene we are using below code

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    //int sheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int swidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int px=swidth/11;
    bW.setWidth(px);
    bE.setWidth(px);
    bR.setWidth(px);
    bT.setWidth(px);
    bY.setWidth(px);
    bU.setWidth(px);
    bI.setWidth(px);
    bO.setWidth(px);
    bP.setWidth(px);
```

somehow the width of button is not changed in any manner it remains the same

Comment: Why don't you just use a horizontal `LinearLayout` and let the OS position and size the buttons for you?

Comment: for some reason i designed qwerty keypad on the screen
if OS positioned and size the button it look wierd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with this solution

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
    params.width=px;
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i consider you buttons to be images, that you have set using the `Selector file`, then you need to keep those files in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, and `drawable-ldpi`, and the images will **accomodate itself according to the available resolution..**

Comment: That's not actually true... dpi corresponds to (approximate) pixel density, not resolution.

Comment: @but resolution depends on the density of these pixels in the screen

Comment: Nope, not at all unless you're saying density in combination with screen (physical) size. You could have a 800x480 hdpi device or a 1920x1080 hdpi device. Completely different resolutions but the same dpi, one will just be physically larger than the other.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra do you think that this will arrange desired nine image in a row

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use **android:layout_weight** property.Its going to consume space depending on the width available.

set to all the buttons as **android:layout_weight="1"**

Try this url

[Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

Comment: if i do that then it will not arrange button in a row another row may be created

Comment: why another row?? suppose you have 5 buttons , set  android:weightSum="5" on layout and set android:layout_weight="1" on each button. It will automatically consume the necessary width.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons and other objects that uses a ninepatch image won't get smaller than the ninepatch itself.

Make sure you are using an appropriate ninepatch image for you buttons that will fit the sizes you need.

Comment: i was searching for the button.. means how we can change the width of button programatically on android