# how to divide the screen with two buttons?

Tags: xml, android-layout

how to divide the screen,s width with two buttons using match_parent. I give match_parent to a button then it fills the screen. I want  two buttons to fill the screen horizontally.

Comment: please use the searchbar on this site - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android

Answer (score 4):

You need to divide the width using the WEIGHT and not by wrap content / match parent etc...

So first of all take a Linear Layout give width as fill_parent, now add weighSum attribute as 2.

Now add 2 buttons with layout_width = 0dp

and add layout_weight = 1 in both the buttons....

The complete code is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Aamir Shah" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Aamir Shah" />

 </LinearLayout>
```