# how to add 3 buttons in a android layout and let each be 33,3% width?

Tags: android

i have a problem, i need to put 3 buttons in a android layout, but:

- they should all be in one row
- they should all be 33,3% width of the display width

i tryed some things with a table and stack layout but did not manage to get it to work with the width.

please help me

Comment: What are the things that you've tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout as the root, then make give each button the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` - which will make them all equal weights, and take up the space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/rvButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/rvButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/rvButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Comment: you should include a `0dip Hack`. that will optimize View-measuring

Answer (score 3):

Take a Linear Layout with Horizontal orientation and put equal weight as below.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you mean either "wrap_content" or "match_parent" :)

Comment: I mean wrap_content only as it doesn't take full screen height. If questionnaire wants to use whole screen height for buttons only then he can use match_parent.

Comment: I was saying because you said "wrap_parent" ...which isn't a valid option

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_with="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="warp_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android_weight_sum="3">
  <View 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=1 />
  <View 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=1 />
  <View 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=1 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your LinearLayout has a sum of 3 and each View inside takes exactly one third in space of it

Comment: Setting the weight sum is optional. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android

Comment: I know, but I think it makes it a little more clearer what happens, AND the Views/Buttons keep their size if one of the Buttons has set its visibility to `GONE`. This may, or may not be intendet behavior