# Android: 3 column layout with fluid width middle column

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table row that is the full width of the screen, which holds 2 textviews and a button.
Which I would ideally like to display as:

[Textview1][Textview2][Button]

Where Textview1 sticks to the left handside and the Button sticks to the right, with Textview2 filling the rest of the available space. I have been looking around but can't find any options that will automatically stretch to fit what is left.

Due to the nature of the app I have to add these table rows and their content automatically, so this is what I have so far.

```
for( Program element :  sampleList)
{           
LayoutParams trLP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
LayoutParams timeLP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
LayoutParams titleLP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
LayoutParams moreInfoLP = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

//Table row to hold details
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(trLP);

//Time
TextView time = new TextView(this);
time.setText(element.getTime());
timeLP.width=50;
timeLP.gravity=1;
time.setLayoutParams(timeLP);

//Title
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setText(element.getTitle());
title.setLayoutParams(titleLP);

//Button
moreInfo = new Button(this);
moreInfo.setText("More Info");

//Add to text views to table row
tr.addView(time);
tr.addView(title);
tr.addView(moreInfo);

holder.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));              
}
```

The above works but doesn't display as I would like obviously, because of the wrap_content on the middle textview, I know I could hardcode a width but would very much like to stay away from that scenario. Is what I'm attempting to achieve even possible with the current code I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try out the `weight` property of LayoutParameters. In your case, set the outer element's weights to 0 and the weight of the center element to 1. This should make the center element to take as much space as possible. However, the weight property sometimes works a bit strange.

Also take a look at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Mig Layout for this (http://www.miglayout.com/ and https://github.com/saynomoo/mig4android) as it does make this sort of thing easier. I'm no expect but the fill and grow constraints look like they should do the job you need.