# Android, custom view class disorders weight of linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

Possible duplicate of [Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698817/513413)

Hi,

I have strange issue. I have designed a custom widget that has linear layout with three buttons. It's code is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tbBrowse"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_browse"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tbHotSpot"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_hotspot"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tbMatches"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_matches"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's look and feel is like this which seems okay:

[image]

I have added this widget to my class (android:id="@+id/Footer"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.belldigital.widget.HeaderBar"
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.belldigital.widget.FooterBar"
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/Header"
        android:layout_above="@id/Footer"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Since, no gravity is defined in 'view' declaration I expect to see same look and feel like first image but I see following image in both emulator and real device.

[image]

What you think? It might be okay if I redesign my widget based on Relative layout. However, I thing current design is okay but why 'view' widget disorder my arrangement?
Any comment/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed above 'view' to following then my problem solved, magically :)

```
<view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.belldigital.widget.FooterBar"
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
```