# Creating a keypad screen in Android

Tags: android, layout

I need to create an activity where the screen is a keypad. At the top the PIN is displayed and below this are large buttons with the numbers 0 to 9 arranged in 4 rows and 3 columns (a delete key and OK button are included). The keypad needs to resize its buttons with different screen sizes. What is the preferred way of doing this? Should it be done (can it be done) using only Relative layouts or with Linear layouts or with both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear layouts and weighting should do the trick.

[See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android/)