# place textview and edittext in same line

Tags: android, xml

I want to place a `TextView` and an `Editext` in same line but it may looks like `TextView` is placing above `EditText`. I've tried all solutions on SO but it didn't work for me exactly.

[image]

Here is my code

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="From"
            android:textColor="#000fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

It places the `EditText` above `TextView`.

Comment: Set align bottom in edit text to textview

Comment: try to give edittext property torightof textview

Comment: android:layout_toRightOf="@id/from" when i wrote it just display textview.

Comment: can you just try this <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/from" ..../>

Comment: when i change layout_width of textview to wrap_content,it display both but still not look like as shown in image.

Comment: use the `android:layout_weight` attribute in your `EditText` and `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using LinearLayout with horizontal orientation

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="From"
            android:textColor="#000fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:inputType="number"
             />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it place both textview and edittext correctly but i want that it looks like textview over edittext

Comment: You want to show editText over textView so that textView is not visible?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `android:layout_weight`. You can view example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android). The `android:layout_weight` works only in `Linearlayout`. You can also define a `LinearLayout` inside the `RelativeLayout` you've defined.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".60"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="From"
        android:textColor="#000fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this solution

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From"
        android:textColor="#000fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="sdjgsjgjb,,b,bm,m,sjksjkjjhks"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/from"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you have given property `fill_parent` to edit text,update it as this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/from" />
```