# Positioning elements with percentage

Tags: android, layout, percentage

i want to put, for example, 9 elements (others layouts or imageviews) in rows of three. In html I would put each div with 33.3% height/width and would word.

How can i do that in android layout XML? I can't find any info about percentage or positioning like that...

Thanks folks!

Comment: You can use LinearLayout with weights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android

Answer (score 1):

you can use either GridView or simple LinearLayout with 3 item each row with layout weight 1 for each column. Unlike GridView (or ListView), if you use LinearLayout it wont be reused when View draw outside screen. 
here simple using simple LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried something like this, but how can I add other row and manage heights (want to use all screen). thanks!

Comment: just wrap it inside vertical LinearLayout, I update my answer to make it more clear. But I can't say it is always best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

just replace those drawables

use `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` will solve ur problem here

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/men_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Men&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/womenLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/women_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Women&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/kidLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/kids_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Kid&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/costumeLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/costume_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Costume&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/winnerLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/winner_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Winner&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/partiesLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/parties_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Parties"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selFieLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/selfie_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Selfie&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/group_icon" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Groups"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/proLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Pro&apos;s"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```