# set Adview Banner at bottom of LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, adview

Hi following is my code,
i want AdView to be displayed at the bottom of the screen but in my code its appearing below the last control,
I set gravity as bottom as well as layout-gravity as bottom event though there is no luck for me,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/playscreenbg"
tools:context="com.exp.exp.ExpActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_utilities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_highscore_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:enabled="false" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sound_off_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:enabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_level_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_easy_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_easy_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:shadowRadius="3.0"
        android:textColor="#00e589"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_normal_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_normal_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:textColor="#00e589"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_hard_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hard_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:textColor="#00e589"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      />
```

Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at [layout_weight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android) property and try to give the AdView layout_weight 0 with the container LinearLayout weightSum 1 and ll_utilities LinearLayout the layout_weight to 1 (or other layout which suits you best)

Comment: pls post ur desired image..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u should use weight and weightSum properties for ur linear layout.

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.exp.exp.ExpActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_utilities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_highscore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_Logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_level_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_easy_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:shadowRadius="3.0"
                android:textColor="#00e589"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_normal_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:shadowRadius="2.0"
                android:textColor="#00e589"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_hard_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:shadowRadius="2.0"
                android:textColor="#00e589"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                android:gravity="bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this blank view above `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView />` view.

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to use one more linear layout for ads


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/playscreenbg"
tools:context="com.exp.exp.ExpActivity"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_utilities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_highscore_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:enabled="false" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sound_off_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:enabled="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_level_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_easy_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_easy_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:shadowRadius="3.0"
        android:textColor="#00e589"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_normal_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_normal_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:textColor="#00e589"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/main_hard_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hard_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:textColor="#00e589"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:enabled="false" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_utilities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't keep parent layout as [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) and adView at bottom of layout: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adrian as suggested use the weight property of linear layouts.Below my snippet contains a relative parent container because the way you are setting the widgets using nested linear layouts will surely cause overdraw issues as well as bad rendering performance.Instead use a relative layout and get the desired result.Also nested weights is also bad for performance.Just saying.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/playscreenbg"
                tools:context="com.exp.exp.ExpActivity"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_highscore_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_sound"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sound_off_selector"
        android:onClick="onClickLevels"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_Logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_highscore"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_level_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_easy_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_easy_selector"
            android:onClick="onClickLevels"
            android:shadowRadius="3.0"
            android:textColor="#00e589"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_normal_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_normal_selector"
            android:onClick="onClickLevels"
            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:textColor="#00e589"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_hard_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_hard_selector"
            android:onClick="onClickLevels"
            android:shadowRadius="2.0"
            android:textColor="#00e589"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:enabled="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

        android:id="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace with your xml file code

  <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <LinearLayout
                     android:id="@+id/container"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="@drawable/playscreenbg"
                     tools:context="com.exp.exp.ExpActivity"
                     android:orientation="vertical">

                     <LinearLayout
                         android:id="@+id/ll_utilities"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:orientation="horizontal"
                         android:layout_gravity="right"
                         android:gravity="right">
                             <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btn_highscore"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:background="@drawable/btn_highscore_selector"
                                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                                android:enabled="false" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_sound_off_selector"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:enabled="false" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_level_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_easy_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_easy_selector"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:shadowRadius="3.0"
                android:textColor="#00e589"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_normal_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_normal_selector"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:shadowRadius="2.0"
                android:textColor="#00e589"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_hard_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_hard_selector"
                android:onClick="onClickLevels"
                android:shadowRadius="2.0"
                android:textColor="#00e589"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:enabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/adViewLandingPage"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              ads:adSize="BANNER"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              />

        </RelativeLayout>
```