# Why doesn't the listview item height change?

Tags: android, listview

My listview is set as:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="5dp">

    </ListView>
```

I load items based on the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="0px"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0px"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:textSize="25sp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason the line `android:layout_height="200dp"` has no effect. Regardless whether I write 200dp or 20dp android shows the same item height.
What do I have to change to get the item height that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `View` only have `LayoutParam` if it's inside a layout.
The moment you inflate a view without a parent layout, any XML `layout_` attribute is ignored.

So to answer the question, you have to inflate the view with the parent, like this:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView =
              LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                   .inflate(R.layout.layout_name, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` with id of **topbar** two main childs those are a `TextView` with id of **place** and a `LinearLayout` with id of **right**. You did not set any height values on this childs. They are set as `wrap_content`. So they will extend with respect to content. If your content is short, they will not extend to 200dp.

- First thing you can do is set this two childs `layout_height` as
  `fill_parent`,
- If you don't want or like first solution then you should research `layout_weight` usage on `LinearLayout`. Check [Linear Layout and weight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android) .

Good luck.