# Splitting the screen into thirds

Tags: java, android

My program has 5 'anchor' points and I would like to calculate these points in the onCreate so regardless of what screen size, they will still have the same anchor points to scale. At first I was attempting to pull dpi and convert to px...

```
 final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me. What would be the best way to evenly split the screen into spots like:

```
 -  -
-  -  -
 -  -
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it in an XML way?

We will just play with the weight of the views. if you have a weightSum of 2 then the the two views with layout_gravity of 1 will split the screen in two half equal to each other.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more info on weight check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean).