# Android Layout limit textSize in listView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to create a view from a Custom List.

See picture below

[image: layout]

Colors :
- blue is the Layout of the view
- pink is a row from the list
- red is a picture, size fixed located to the left
- grey is a place to display 2 texts : a label and a value
- orange is another picture, size fixed, which should be located to the right

I read a lot about layouts, but can't find a way to do this.

Whatever I try, if the text is too long it goes under the orange picture.

Here is the XML I'm using :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flower_picture"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LABEL" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wateredbutton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried many things but can't find a way to limit the size of the text without setting a textSize of a layout_width.

I assumed that android would be able to detect that there are 3 layouts to display in a row, and would be able to limit the middle one to the desired size if needed.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: did you give maxLength?

Comment: just give weight to each views look at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android>

Comment: also avoid using fill_parent 
this constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code which is not overlap each other and limit your text in TextView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flower_picture"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wateredbutton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/wateredbutton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flower_picture"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Perfiect, it did the trick, with the ellipsize still working, and no length or weight so the pictures don't scale. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flower_picture"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="LABEL" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wateredbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this will solve your problem,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to limit your text view in a row. use relative layout and add toRightOff and give the picture id of right picture and it will limit it to left of picture and wont cut behind the picture