# LinearLayout issue on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, orientation

My goal is to have a `TextView` at the right of the Title, Stars and Thoughts.
I normally know how to do it with `orientation="horizontal"` but actually this is quite tricky because I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/white">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/offertitle"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:textSize="24dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/troisieme"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="15dp"
                            android:id="@+id/offerstars"
                            android:src="@drawable/stars" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:id="@+id/offerthoughts"
                            android:text="53 avis"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/offer_price"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="blablabla"
                    android:background="#D3D3D3"/>
```

Here is an image:

[image: Doodle]

Comment: Can you show us an example of what is your desired output?

Comment: can you attach an image from what you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your quick answers !

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'll delete my question but keep in mind that this was my first question, i never asked or answered before ! I'm just a beginner that got stuck for days and days on the same error, sorry for bad langage and all things else.

Comment: Well I can't delete this question but I "swear" a lot and I'm sorry if I offended anyone. But besides this, what else is wrong with my question ?

Comment: You don't have to delete the question, just bear it in mind for the future. Please also don't roll back edits here - even after the swearing is removed, it was far too chatty. If you wish to insist on your version, please ping me with `@halfer` and I'll ask a moderator for their opinion.

Comment: Okay got it ! But the thing is that i'm 17 y.o and french so it's hard for me to " not be "chatty" ", this isn't on purpose i just try to explain myself ^^ But thanks for your answers, I'll try to do my best for the future, have good night (or day) ! See you soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Layout which contains title and etc. and is side by side with your TextView has width set as match_parent, it's wrong. there is no space for TextView then, below you have your design corrected. It has set width as **0dp** and weight as **1** - so it fills available space.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offertitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/troisieme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/offerstars"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_start"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offerthoughts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="53 avis"
                android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offer_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="blablabla"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it worked first time ! And by the way I understood why it didn't work, DOUBLE THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve some part to left and some part to right you can go with **RelativeLayout**

If you still want to do in **Linearlayout** than you should use [Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698817/linear-layout-and-weight-in-android) inside it.

You can do like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/offer_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offertitle"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/troisieme"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/offerstars"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/offerthoughts"
                android:text="53 avis"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/offer_price"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="blablabla"
        android:background="#D3D3D3"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use `layout_weight` and `weightSum` to manage portions in of layout. and set `width` to `0dp` so weight can affect.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="#FFFFF0"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offertitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24dp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/troisieme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/offerstars"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offerthoughts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="53 avis"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offer_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="blablabla"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For future readers, would you edit this answer to show how it would help?