# How to give space between list items for recylerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: this is screenshot am getting output .after first and second listitem there should be space and not occupying right side want to occupy background blue coloc]

Between `id1 and id2` want some `space`
In the below layout am displaying `recylerview` list of items having two attributes are there one is title and `listview`.

want to space between list of items should occupy full screen.

> layoutfile

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_create_account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Info"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="top"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the below xml am displaying list of items available like name , email and phone these are the attributes in the list

> list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_create_account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_id"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/email"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can give padding to row item parent item or you can use `addItemDecoration`

Comment: `list.xml` in second `LinearLayout` give `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` and remove from RecyclerVIew

Comment: Most simple way it set a margin to root `LinearLayout`  of `list.xml`

Comment: what is the use of removing margin

Comment: In `list.xml` file first change height of parent layout to `wrap_content` and apply `paddingTop = "20dp"` to it. Also remove         `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` from recyclerview.

Comment: i have edited my post

Comment: dear simply remove `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` from RecyclerView and add in `list.xml` parent `LinearLayout` thats it @jyothichandra

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
android:layout_weight
```

you can find information about the weight on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4517358/9349671). Just adapt it to `layout_height` instead of layout-with.

Comment: `weight` ? Why ? There are `paddingTop` and item decoration for recyclerview and it's item.

Comment: Right @Piyush and `weight` is used equal space

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` to your parent view `LinearLayout` of list.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your main goal is  highlight particular item..

> 1. use divider

**here the example :** 
https://medium.com/@szholdiyarov/how-to-add-divider-to-list-and-recycler-views-858344450401

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecor = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext, HORIZONTAL);

<!--addItemDecoration to recyclerView -->

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecor);
```

You can also change its orientation using `itemDecor.setOrientation(VERTICAL)` or drawable image by calling a method `itemDecor.setDrawable(Drawable divider)`.

But sometimes you need to customise the way of drawing the divider. For example, you might want to change the divider’s colour on the last element or to not draw a line for the first item.

> 2. use padding or margin as [shreya-prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3530602/shreya-prajapati) suggested..