# How to place one object beneath another with LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.0

I have to use `LinearLayout` to make this little app type thing in Android Studio.

The instructions say we have to use `vertical` orientation for the root tag (and this text at the top says "Here are my widgets") and then `horizontal` orientation for each row. My only issue is how to place things on different rows?

It's supposed to look like:

**Row 1:** "Here are my widgets" (Vert orientation)

**Row 2:** *BUTTON* *IMAGEBUTTON*

**Row 3:** *CHECKBOX* *SWITCH*

My issue is, when I make a new nested `LinearLayout`, it shows up on row 2. How do I make a row 3 with `horizontal` orientation? I tried putting an empty `LinearLayout` thing with `vertical` orientation to maybe split the two rows up, but that didn't work. How do I make the `CheckBox` and switch show up beneath the buttons? I have to use `LinearLayout`, and the orientation has to be horizontal. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_message"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:text="@string/ButtonText" />

<ImageButton
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/flag"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your layout will look like briefly:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    // other attributes... > 

    <TextView
        // This is ROW 1!
        //welcome text goes here />

    <LinearLayout
        // This is ROW 2!
        android:orientation="horizontal">

           <Button
               ... />

           <ImageButton 
                .../>

     </LinearLayout>   <-- Closing of the Row2 horizontal LinearLayout


    <LinearLayout
        // This is ROW 3!
        android:orientation="horizontal">

           <CheckBox
                ... />

           <Switch
                 .../>

     </LinearLayout> <-- Closing of the Row3 horizontal LinearLayout
</LinearLayout> <-- Closing of the root vertical LinearLayout
```

You can fill in additional attributes (id, height, width, etc... ) depending on your needs.

I noticed you used `android:layout_weight` attribute to each `View`s. If you use this attribute, it is desirable to use `android:weightSum` to the `View`s parent layout. For example, if you need 50:50 width ratio of your `Button` and `ImageButton`:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:weightSum="2">  <--- starting of Row2 LinearLayout

      <Button
          android:layout_weight="1"     ... />

      <ImageButton 
          android:layout_weight="1      ... />

</LinearLayout> <--- closing of Row2 LinearLayout
```

For more details about `weight`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4517358/9867072) :)

Comment: That makes sense, didn't realize I had to close off the first one. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Griff2 Glad my answer helped you. It will be great if you can accept my answer :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <Button
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Button one" />

    <ImageButton
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Check Box"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```